# F# Generic Programming - Using members

Tags: generics, f#, constraints

Suppose I have a family of types which support a given member function, like the `Property` member below:

```
type FooA = {...} with

    member this.Property = ...

type FooB = {...} with

    member this.Property = ...
```

Suppose the member Property returns an integer for each of the the above types. Now, I wan to write a generic function that could do the following:

```
let sum (a: 'T) (b: 'U) = a.Property + b.Property
```

I am used to write the following in C++:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
int sum(T a, U b)
{
    return a.Property + b.Property;
}
```

How would be an equivalent implementation in F#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to do this in F#, but it isn't idiomatic:

```
let inline sum a b = (^T : (member Property : int) a) + (^U : (member Property : int) b)
```

In general, .NET generics are very different from C++ templates, so it's probably worth learning about their differences first before trying to emulate C++ in F#.  The general .NET philosophy is that operations are defined by nominal types rather than structural types.  In your example you could define an interface exposing a `Property` property, which your two classes implement, and then your `sum` function would take instances of that interface.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233215.aspx for more information on F# generics; for a brief comparison of .NET generics versus C++ templates see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/branbray/archive/2003/11/19/51023.aspx (or really anything that comes up when you Google ".NET generics C++ templates").

Comment: It may not be idiomatic, but it can be damn handy. For example, I use this to get easy access to all those convenient explicit conversion operators defined on XElement and XAttribute: `let inline xval (x : ^a when ^a :> XObject) : ^b = ((^a or ^b) : (static member op_Explicit : ^a -> ^b) x)` Then I can just do something like this: `let foo:int = xval myElement`

Comment: Thanks. Though more verbose than the C++ version, it works. Where can I learn more about generics in F#?

Comment: @Allan - I've edited my answer to add a few links to further reading.

Comment: Brain-exploding syntax. I love f#!

Answer (score 2):

I think that the clean approach in this case (even in F#) is to use basic object-oriented programming and define an interface with the members you require (e.g. `Property`):

```
type IHasProperty =
  abstract Property : int
```

Note that F# infers that we're declaring an interface, because it has only abstract members and no constructor. Then you can implement the interface in your types:

```
type FooA = {...} 
  interface IHasProperty with
    member this.Property = ... 

type FooB = {...} 
  interface IHasProperty with
    member this.Property = ...
```

It is worth pointing out that any F# types (including records, discriminated unions and of course classes) can implement interfaces. Now, the generic function can just take two arguments of the type `IHasProperty`:

```
let sum (a: IHasProperty) (b: IHasProperty) = a.Property + b.Property
```

You don't even need generics in this case, but there are several tricks that generics can do with interfaces too - you can require the type parameter `T` to implement some specified interface, but this is not needed here, because F# will automatically convert arguments from types like `FooA` to the interface when you write `sum f1 f2`.

The use of interfaces and types that are immutable makes often a very good sense in F#. There may be a "more functional" solution to your problem, but that would require more context.

Comment: What if I can't change the code? That is, the types already implement the member Property without using interfaces. It is not my case; just curious.

Comment: @Allan: In that case, the only option would proably be to use static member constraints as suggested by kvb.

Comment: For example, in a linear algebra library, I could have many kinds of matrices (e.g. Dense, Sparse, Band, etc.). In C++ I would write arithmetic operations using template in such way that could work for any of these matrices. For an addition function, for example, I would require that the type provides the member operator(i,j) to access the matrix entry i,j.

Answer (score 2):

C++ templates roughly use a kind of 'structural static subtyping' relation (somewhat like 'duck typing'), whereas .NET generics use nominal subtyping.  As @kvb says, you can emulate the C++ stuff with `inline` and static member constraints in F#, but be very wary of doing this.  There are a few other ways to express a similar relation; @Tomas shows one (OO subtyping), and another would be to pass a method dictionary (that knows how to project out .Property from a fixed set of types).  (If this were Haskell, you could use typeclasses.)